# Extract words within a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
[(net, asset), (amount, asset), (connect, asset), (net, asset), (check, asset), (service, asset), (adapt, asset)] | [(part, asset)]
```

I want to extract only the first words after the open bracket. My output should be -

```
net amount connect net check service adapt part
```

data

```
[(net, asset), (amount, asset), (connect, asset), (net, asset), (check, asset), (service, asset), (adapt, asset)] | [(part, asset)]
```

I tried the following.

```
p=re.compile("'('(.*)','")
result = p.search(data)
result.group(1)
```

But this pattern matching is not working. Any help please

Comment: `p=re.compile("'('(\w*)','")` or `p=re.compile("'('(.*?)','")`

Comment: re.findall(r'(\w+),', text)

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of regex here: https://regex101.com/r/kAXpNA/1.

```
re.findall('\((.*?),', '[(net, asset), (amount, asset), (connect, asset), (net, asset), (check, asset), (service, asset), (adapt, asset)] | [(part, asset)]')
#['net', 'amount', 'connect', 'net', 'check', 'service', 'adapt', 'part']
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues with your current pattern:

```
p=re.compile("'('(.*)','")
```

- The single quotes in your pattern are literal single quote chars that it's searching your string for. Your data doesn't have any single quotes, so it's not matching.
- You haven't escaped the parenthesis at the beginning. `(` and `)` are special chars in regexes that are used to create [regex groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping). To literally match a parenthesis you need to do `\(`.
- Also `.*` matches any char, and the regex will end up trying to match as many characters as it can, meaning it will span multiple pairs in your string. (as something like `"(net, asset), (amount, asset), (connect,"` does in fact satisfy that pattern) If you know the elements you're looking for instead are all word chars, as they are in your example, you could try doing `\w*` instead.

Finally [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) only looks for the first match that it encounters. You instead want to use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to get every instance of your pattern in the string. So the result would be:

```
p=re.compile("\((\w*),")
result = p.findall(data)
result
# ['net', 'amount', 'connect', 'net', 'check', 'service', 'adapt', 'part']
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
p = re.compile(r'\((\w+),')
result = p.search(data)
result.group(1)
```

Or if you want to have **all** first words after a `(`, write:

```
[ m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(p, data)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern tries to match single quotes which are not present in the example data and you have to escape the opening parenthesis to match it literally.

The `.*` is greedy which will first match until the end of the string and then will backtrack matching the last comma to fulfill the whole pattern. You might turn that into a lazy quantifier `.+?` and use a plus to match it 1+ times.

Another way to get your matches if you want to match more than only word characters and you don't want to match an opening parenthesis of a comma is to  use a negated character class:

```
\(([^,(]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(` literally
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `[^,(]+` Negated character class, match 1+ times not `,` or `(`
- `)` Close capturing group

For example

```
import re
regex = r"\(([^,(]+)"
data = "[(net, asset), (amount, asset), (connect, asset), (net, asset), (check, asset), (service, asset), (adapt, asset)] | [(part, asset)]"
print(re.findall(regex, data))

# ['net', 'amount', 'connect', 'net', 'check', 'service', 'adapt', 'part']
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OWkWOa/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wrNiOX)